# Div class not working in php

Tags: php, html

I would greatly appreciate any help I can get on this matter. I am using xampp on an Ubuntu Linux Server OS. I have a filed saved as template.php. I have defined a style on template.php which contains a div class "spcout". When I try and use "spcout", the text in the  tags should spread themselves out evenly in a line over the width of the web page. Unfortunately, it's not happening. It appears my div class is somehow not being read. I tried using the same code in a .html file and it works when I open the file locally. If i upload the same html file onto the web server, that same html file will not display correctly. Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

```
<style type="text/css"> 
ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li
{
    display:inline;
}

div.spcout
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

div.spcout span
{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
<img src="images\baseimage.png">

<div class="spcout">
<span>code 1</span>
<span>code 1</span>
<span>code 1</span>
</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: What's the expected output? Can you post a screenshot of expected result?

Comment: You have wrong quotes: `type=”text/css”` -> `type="text/css"`

Comment: The quote is correct. It just displayed wrongly when I copied and pasted it here.

Comment: @AdrianTeo Upload them to imgur and paste the link :)

Comment: http://imgur.com/UErj1LZ

thanks @Nilzone!

Comment: @AdrianTeo http://jsfiddle.net/MkbqN/ - what is wrong with this? besides the fact that the image is not properly loaded since it's stored locally

Comment: @Nilzone: Exactly my point. The code is correct but for some reason on xampp running on Ubuntu, this is what I see: http://imgur.com/p1rkZNR

Comment: try to give permission for the files

Comment: @AdrianTeo could you upload the picture you're using as well so I can test further?

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css"> 

div.spcout span
{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-right:5px
}
</style>

<div id="container">
<img src="images\baseimage.png">

<div class="spcout">
<span>code 1</span>
<span>code 1</span>
<span>code 1</span>
</div>    
</div>
```